# Is there a way to disable checkbox in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm trying to disable a checkbox input in jqgrid.

I used this custom formatter on the colModel array for the field

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
           {
                return '<input type="checkbox" value="' + cellvalue + '" ' + (rowObject.IsActive== true ? 'checked="checked"' : '') + ' ' + (rowObject.IsEnabled == false ? 'disabled="disable"' : '') + '/>';
           }
```

This work as I want some rows can be checked when is allowed, but the problem is when I checked any of those rows and I get the value like this:

```
$('#jqgTable').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'IsActive');
```

Is returnig the input html tag `<input type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked">`, but always is `true` using `$($('#jqgTable').jqGrid('getCell', "idSelected", 'IsActive')).is(':checked')`.

Before I used the `formatter: "checkbox"` and with `$('#jqgTable').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'IsActive');` I get `Yes` or `No`so I can do what I need, but all checkbox are enable.

I tried too this other solution

I used with `formatter: "checkbox"` and the function

```
    beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.is(":checkbox")) {
            var canChange = $("#jqgTable").jqGrid('getRowData', rowid).IsEnabled == 'false' ? false : true;
            if ($("#jqgTable").jqGrid('getRowData', rowid).IsEnabled == 'false' ? false : true) {
                UpdateState(rowid);
            }
            else
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        return true;
    },
```

This works but the checkbox seems looks like I can change it.

All code using the first option

```
    $("#jqgTable").jqGrid({
        data: data,
        datatype: "local",
        colNames: [
            'Checkbox'
            ,'Enable'
        ],
        colModel: [    
            {
                name: 'IsActive', label: "Active", width: 100,
                //formatter: 'checkbox',
                align: "center", stype: "select",
                searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: "true:Si;false:No" },
                editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', formatoptions: { disabled: false },
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
                {
                    return '<input type="checkbox" value="' + cellvalue + '" ' + (rowObject.IsActive == true ? 'checked="checked"' : '') + ' ' + (rowObject.IsEnable == false ? 'disabled="disable"' : '') + '/>';
                }
            },
            { 
                name: 'IsEnable', label: '', width: 1, hidden: true 
            },
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        mtype: 'GET',
        loadonce: true,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        pager: '#jqgTablePager',
        sortable: true,
        multiselect: false,
        pageable: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'desc',
        gridview: true,
        autowidth: false,
        width: 100,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        altRows: true,       
        altclass: "myAltRowClass",       
        gridComplete: function (){
                //Second option
        },
        beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
            var $target = $(e.target);
            if ($target.is(":checkbox")) {
                var canChange = $("#jqgTable").jqGrid('getRowData', rowid).IsEnabled == 'false' ? false : true;
                if ($("#jqgTable").jqGrid('getRowData', rowid).IsEnabled == 'false' ? false : true) {
                    UpdateState(rowid);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    $('#jqgTable').jqGrid('navGrid', '#jqgTablePager',
    {
       edit: false,
       add: false,
       del: false,
       search: true,
       searchtext: "Search"
    },
    //Edit
    {},
    //Add
    {},
    //Delete
    {},
    //Search
    {
       closeAfterSearch: true,
       closeAfterReset: true,
       closeOnEscape: false,
       searchOnEnter: true,
       multipleSearch: true,
       multipleGroup: false,
       showQuery: false
    }
    ).navButtonAdd('#jqgTablePager', { title: "Title", caption: "Caption", buttonicon: 'ui-icon-wrench', onClickButton: function () { ShowGroup(); }, position: "last" })
    .navButtonAdd('#jqgTablePager', { title: "Delete", caption: "", buttonicon: 'ui-icon-close', onClickButton: function () { CleanGroup(); }, position: "last" });
    $("#jqgTable").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Thank You!

**Update**

I tried with the second option and I add in the gridComplete function this to apply a css style `disabled` with `cursor: not-allowed`:

```
var ids = $("#jqgTable").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
         
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var id = ids[i];
    var isEditable = $("#jqgTable").jqGrid('getRowData', id).IsEnabled == 'false' ? false : true;
    if (!isEditable)
        $("#jqgTable").jqGrid('setCell', id, 'IsActive', '', 'disabled', {disabled : true});
}
```

Works fine.

**Update**

At the end I did this:

I left the default formatter for checkbox in the ColModel
And on the gridComplete function I add:

```
   var IsEnabled = $("#jqgTable").jqGrid('getRowData', id).IsEnabled == 'false' ? false : true;
   var IsActive = $("#jqgTable").jqGrid('getRowData', id).IsActive == 'false' ? false : true;
   if (!IsEnabled)
   {
       $("#jqgTable").jqGrid('setRowData', id, { IsActive: '<input type="checkbox" ' + (IsActive == true ? 'checked="checked"' : '') + ' disabled="disable/>'});
   }
```

Comment: In case you IsActive is a checkbox (which is first child of the table cell) I'm not sure your updated code will work correct which uses setCell

Comment: yes, that was a problem, but in the css I use the selector for the input ".disabled input[type="checkbox"]" to apply the css

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve your problem you should define unformat function again with

```
custom formatter.  so if your custom formatter is :

formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
           {
                return '<input type="checkbox" value="' + cellvalue + '" ' + (rowObject.IsActive== true ? 'checked="checked"' : '') + ' ' + (rowObject.IsEnabled == false ? 'disabled="disable"' : '') + '/>';
           }
```

Define in colModel the unformat like:

```
unformat : function(cellvalue, options, cell) {
    return $("input",cell).is(":checked")=== true;              
}
```

Note that we analyze the **cell** and not the **cellvalue**.

We tested this in Guriddo jqGrid and it is working as expected.

Now using getCell and getRowData will return true or false depending if the check box is checked

Comment: Where you put the unformat function? It should be exactly  after formatter in the colModel where you define the checkbox value. Another problem could be the version of jqGrid used? Which version of jqGrid is used? Look at this docs on how to use the [unformat function](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/formatters/#unformatting)

Comment: I putted exactly after the formatter in the colModel for that field. The version is jqGrid  4.8.0 - free jqGrid. Thanks I will checked.